# Is it possible to analyze items' performance from different exams using the same questions but with a different order in each version?

Tags: r, r-exams

We produced five `exams2nops` exams using the same groups of items, with randomized order. All of them were schoice items. As such, five different `*.rds` files were obtained, each of them will be used with the correspondent scanned exams. I noticed that in those `*.rds` files to be used in the `nops_eval` there is the information about the `*.rmd` which as used to produce that exams' question. E.g.:

[image]

However, after producing the the `nops_eval.csv` that information is lost.
I would like to merge all five `nops_eval.csv` files using the `*.rmd` information to match each question. Since the same question (e.g. exercise 22) can be genareted from the different `*.rmd` files. All the same 22 `*.rmd` files were used in all exams (all have the same 22 questions but with different orders.

I would like to obtain a data frame with the merged csv to allow me to conduct Item Response Theory and Rasch modeling analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can merge the information from the CSV files by reordering them based on the file/name information from the RDS files. Below I illustrate how to do this using the `check.*` columns from the CSV files. These are typically closest to what I need for doing an IRT analysis.

First, you read the CSV and RDS from the first version of the exam:

```
eval1 <- read.csv2("/path/to/first/nops_eval.csv", dec = ".")
metainfo1 <- readRDS("/path/to/first/exam.rds")
```

Then, you only extract the `check.*` columns and use the exercise file names as column names.

```
eval1 <- eval1[, paste0("check.", 1:length(metainfo1[[1]]))]
names(eval1) <- sapply(metainfo1[[1]], function(x) x$metainfo$file)
```

I'm using `$file` here because it is always unique across exercises. If `$name` is also unique in your case and has the better labels, you can also use that instead.

Then you do the same for the second version of the exam:

```
eval2 <- read.csv2("/path/to/second/nops_eval.csv", dec = ".")
metainfo2 <- readRDS("/path/to/second/exam.rds")
eval2 <- eval2[, paste0("check.", 1:length(metainfo2[[1]]))]
names(eval2) <- sapply(metainfo2[[1]], function(x) x$metainfo$file)
```

If the same exercises have been used in the construction of the two version, the column names of `eval1` and `eval2` are the same, just in a different order. Then you can simply do

```
eval2 <- eval2[, names(eval1)]
```

to reorder the columns of `eval2` to match those of `eval1`. Subsequently, you can do:

```
eval <- rbind(eval1, eval2)
```

If you have more than two versions of the exam, you just iterate the same code and `rbind()` everything together in the end.

Similar code can also be used if the exercises are just partially overlapping between the versions of the exercise. In that case I first construct a large enough `NA` matrix with the merged exercise file names and then insert the results:

```
n1 <- nrow(eval1)
n2 <- nrow(eval2)
nam <- unique(c(names(eval1), names(eval2)))
eval <- matrix(NA, nrow = n1 + n2, ncol = length(nam))
colnames(eval) <- nam
eval[1:n1, names(eval1)] <- as.matrix(eval1)
eval[(n1 + 1):(n1 + n2), names(eval2)] <- as.matrix(eval2)
```

Again you would need to iterate suitably to merge more than two versions.

In either case the resulting `eval` could then be processed further to become the IRT matrix for subsquent analysis.